# DataTable must be set prior to using DataView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, binding, ado.net

Hi i did look at search result for " DataTable must be set prior to using DataView." but none of their solutions fixed my problem or pointed me in the right direction.

Were am i going wrong here, when i press a header to sort out the gridview table i just get an error and no sorting. The error is the same as my title for this post.

EDIT: Not sure if its relevant but i populate the gridview on page load from a MS SQL database

**Mark-up**

```
<asp:GridView ID="_propertyGridView" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="PropertyRowCommand"  Width="100%">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Ref" SortExpression="Id" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"   />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PostCode" HeaderText="Post Code" SortExpression="PostCode" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContractsFinishedOn" HeaderText="Contract Signed On" SortExpression="ContractsFinishedOn" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Mobile" HeaderText="Mobile No." SortExpression="Mobile" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LandLordEmail" HeaderText="Owners Email" SortExpression="LandLordEmail" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MoveInDate" HeaderText="Move In Date" SortExpression="MoveInDate" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="_tenantPaymentCheckBox" runat="server" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#Bind("TenantReceipt") %>' />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="_tenantPaymentLink" Text="Send Tenant Receipt" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("Id") %>' CommandName="TenantEmail" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('This will email &amp; sms the tenant, please make sure its correct');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="_landlordInfoCheckBox" runat="server" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#Bind("LandlordInfo") %>' />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="_landlordInfoLink" Text="Request Landlord Info" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("Id") %>' CommandName="LandlordInfoEmail" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('This will email &amp; sms the landlord, please make sure its correct');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status3">
            <ItemTemplate >
                <asp:CheckBox ID="_landlordRentCheckBox" runat="server" Enabled="false" Checked='<%#Bind("LandlordReceipt") %>' />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="_landlordRentLink" Text="Send Landlord Receipt" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("Id") %>' CommandName="LandlordEmail" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('This will email &amp; sms the landlord, please make sure its correct');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
protected void _propertyGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        ViewState["z_sortexpresion"] = e.SortExpression;
        if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
            SortGridView(sortExpression, "DESC");
        }
        else
        {
            GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
            SortGridView(sortExpression, "ASC");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SearchErrorLbl.Text = "error in such";
    }
}

public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["sortDirection"] = value;
    }

}

private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
{
    DTSorting = new DataView(DTSorting, "", sortExpression + " " + direction, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).ToTable();
    _propertyGridView.DataSource = DTSorting;
    _propertyGridView.DataBind();
}

public DataTable DTSorting
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["Sorting"] != null)
            return (DataTable)ViewState["Sorting"];
        else
            return null;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Sorting"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems your `Data-source` is null

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the problem is within `SortGridView` method. You try to use the very same `DTSorting` property you attempt to set as the `table` constructor parameter. If it is null at this point it will most definitely throw an exception. `DataView` needs an existing `DataTable` instance to work with.

I should also mention that the current implementation will likely create multiple `DataTable` instances that won't ever get disposed of. One thing for sure is that you aren't disposing of the `DataView` object you are creating so that you get your sorted table.

If I were you I would rethink how data should be bound. Storing a `DataTable` object in `ViewState` is bad practice. The full table will be serialized back and forth between the client and the server, resulting in performance loss.

I suggest you read about it here: [View State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't really fix my problem

Comment: @Deviney are you saying that `DTSorting` property never returns `null`?